# Macro in a dynamic sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba.
I am trying to execute a Macro which will work in different sheets. (Each sheet has a data table).

Select a specific column in Dynamic table (which exists in all seven sheets) and calculate in one cell after the last cell in the table (of the specific column) the sum of the cells in the column.

I searched in the site a lot, But I do not exactly understand.
I would appreciate any help

```
Sub Employees()

Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim vSheets() As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim rngFound As range

vSheets = Array("Employees 1", "Employees 2", "Employees 3", "Employees 4", "Employees 5")

For Each vItem In vSheets
    With Worksheets(vItem).Activate
    Set rngFound = .range("1:1").Find(What:="Monthly Salary")
   lRow = wrkSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      wrkSht.Cells(lRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"
      
      
        
    End With
Next vItem  
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so it might help if you include the code you are using in your question...

Comment: Loop through each worksheet and place your code within the loop. When you run into problems or errors; ask a specific question and provide your code identifying the line of code where you are have the problem or error.

Comment: Since I tried all kinds of codes I did not upload.
I have now updated the code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GMalc said - loop through all the worksheets.  A worksheet is part of the worksheets collection and you can loop through collections:

```
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Next Worksheet
```

`Worksheet` must be replaced by a variable to hold the reference to the worksheet, so:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lRow = wrkSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        'Single cell can be referenced with row/column number.
        wrkSht.Cells(lRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"
        'or
        'wrkSht.Cells(lRow, 6).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,F2:F" & lRow - 1 & ")"
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

or if it's a selection of sheets within a larger book you could use:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim vSheets() As Variant
    Dim vItem As Variant
    
    vSheets = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    For Each vItem In vSheets
        With Worksheets(vItem)
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            'Single cell can be referenced with row/column number.
            .Cells(lRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"
            'or
            '.Cells(lRow, 6).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,F2:F" & lRow - 1 & ")"
        End With
    Next vItem

End Sub
```